# Why does the value a function is returning , not reflecting at where it is being called from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, async-await

I have three small files,
`ComponentTest.jsx`

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react"
import updateVariable from "./UpdateVariable"

export default function MainPageTwo(){
    let mainPageVariable={}

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("Ran Use Effect")
        mainPageVariable = updateVariable()
        console.log("DATA: "+mainPageVariable)
    })
    return(<div>
          Test
          </div> );;}
```

`UpdateVariable.js`

```
import UpdateVariableAPI from "./UpdateApiResponse"

export default function updateVariable(){
    for(let i = 0; i<=1; i++){
        if(i===0){
            let values= UpdateVariableAPI() //calling function from 3rd file here
            values.then((messages)=>{
                console.log("Values : "+JSON.stringify(messages))
                return(messages)
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                console.log("error : "+error.message)
                })} } }
```

and `UpdateApiResponse.js.`

```
import axios, * as others from 'axios';
export default async function UpdateVariableAPI(){
    try{
        const response = await axios.get(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`)
        console.log("Values : "+JSON.stringify(response))
        return(response.data)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error.response.data)
    } }
```

In short, The first react component calls the function `updateVariable()` from 2nd file, and in `updateVariable()`, I call `UpdateVariableAPI()` where an api call is made.

When I try to log `mainPageVariable` on useEffect() from first file I get Undefined, but at the same time I do get a proper json response in my third file when I log it.

The following is the output I get:

```
Ran Use Effect
DATA: undefined
Values : {"data":{"page":2,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":7,"emai...(continued...)
```

Comment: There's no `return` in `updateVariable` function's body, and calling it will return `undefined`

Comment: @EnfieldLi there is one in `.then()` right? So the `updateVariable` would return when the `values` promise results in something right? (I may be wrong, I am learning react)

Comment: What is the point of a loop `for(let i = 0; i<=1; i++) { if(i===0){ /*... */ } }`  Why do this loop twice when it does pretty much nothing on the second iteration when i == 1?

Comment: @Wyck That was so that I could change 1 to lets say 5, and have the code make an api call 5 times instead of 1, but i suppose that doesnt work as I think to make 5 api calls I should call the function in the main file 5 times instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fair bit going on here that needs fixing:

First, `ComponentTest.jsx` should be using state, and useEffect should have the empty dependency array.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import updateVariable from "./UpdateVariable";

export default function MainPageTwo() {
  const [mainPageVariable, setMainPageVariable] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Ran Use Effect");
    const updateMainPageVariable = async () => {
      const variable = await updateVariable();
      setMainPageVariable(variable);
      console.log("DATA: " + JSON.stringify(variable));
    };
    updateMainPageVariable();
  }, []);

  return <div>Test</div>;
}
```

Next, I'm not sure what that loop is for, so a bit cleaner:

```
import UpdateVariableAPI from "./UpdateApiResponse";

export default async function updateVariable() {
  try {
    const messages = await UpdateVariableAPI(); // calling function from 3rd file here
    console.log("Values : " + JSON.stringify(messages));
    return messages;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error : " + error.message);
  }
}
```

In this way the function returns the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're assigning the result of `updateVariable` to `mainPageVariable`.

I can't see from the screenshot, but it looks like you may be not returning anything from `updateVariable` and thus, you're getting an `undefined` result.

EDIT: Updating code snippet to express promise/return example. As stated in the comments, the return inside the `then` statement returns for that context and not the context of the function that calls then statement. Suggesting using `finally` and passing the promise upward like so:

updateVariable.js

```
async function updateVariable(){
    for(let i = 0; i<=1; i++){
        if(i===0){
            let values = UpdateVariableAPI(); //calling function from 3rd file here

            values.then((messages)=>{
                console.log("Values : "+JSON.stringify(messages))
                return(messages)
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log("error : "+error.message)
            }).finally( () => {
                return values
            })} 
            
        } 
    }
```

Component using UseEffect:

```
let mainPageVariable: any ={}

useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("Ran Use Effect")
        updateVariable().then( (value) => mainPageVariable = value );
        console.log('DATA: ' + JSON.stringify(mainPageVariable))
    })
```

Comment: but I have added a return statement in `.then()`, why wouldn't that work

Comment: The return value from your `then()` is what the promise resolves to, but you're not doing anything with it. It's like saying `const result = values.then( ...  )` and not doing anything with `result`.

Comment: It's a context issue. That inner return is referring to the context.

Comment: @ray Oh! got you! So if I return the values instead which is a promise. So I just tried that, but my `mainPageVariable` in the main file still returns null, I used `setTimeout(()=>{console.log("DATA: "+JSON.stringify(mainPageVariable))}, 5000)` instead of simple `console.log` in useEffect()

Comment: "then"'s context I mean

Comment: @NeedHelpWithCode see my updated example above. I don't think you need to setTimeout

Comment: What is the point of `finally(() => { return values})` ?  The promise chain that begins `values.then` is unused.  (not returned by `updateVariable`)

Comment: @AshaunThomas Just clarifying, wouldnt the `.finally()` return for the function inside `.then()` instead of the main function?